# How to get a json group

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have json like this :

```
jsons={"books":[
    {"book_1":[ 
        {"title":"DATA 1"},
        {"author":"DATA 2"},
        {"category":"DATA 3"} 
    ]}, 
    {"book_2":[ 
        {"title":"DATA 4"},
        {"author":"DATA 5"},
        {"category":"DATA 6"}
    ]}, 
]};
```

I want to get only book_1 group with jQuery $.each. How to do it ?

And I have 2 array in PHP

```
$array_1 = ("A","B","C");
$array_2 = ("D","E","F");
```

I want json_encode like group :

```
jsons={"array_0":[
    {"array_1":[ 
        {"1":"A"},
        {"2":"B"},
        {"3":"c"} 
    ]}, 
    {"array_2":[ 
        {"1":"D"},
        {"2":"E"},
        {"2":"F"}
    ]}, 
]};
```

How to do it.

Thanks you.

Comment: what code have you tired so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**In jQuery**

```
console.log(jsons.books[0].book_1);
```

Using `$.each()`

```
$(jsons.books).each(function (i, v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```

**In PHP**

```
echo json_encode(array('array_0'=>
        array('array_1'=>$array_1,'array_2'=>$array_2)
     ));
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot, with some nested data I have. Thanks!